# What is the best way to limit access permissions for a group of developers?

Tags: software-development, product-management, development-process

What is the best way to manage a group of developers without giving them access to the whole codebase?

I have a project with a front-end and a back-end. I want to be able to give new developers just part of the project that they can work on and test without giving them access to the whole project.

As three developers, how can we streamline our workflow and make us move faster?

Comment: This question seems largely off-topic for a project management site. It's really an engineering, security, or tooling question, but the fact that it's essentially an opinion poll makes it off-topic on most sites within the SE network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling access to your source code will vary depending on where you are hosting your code and what version control system you are using. You would have to consult the documentation associated with your tools.

However, restricting access to pieces of a system that must be integrated to be delivered is the opposite of what you want to do to streamline your workflow and allow the team to move faster. By restricting people to only viewing and editing part of the code, they will have to document the interfaces, implement against the documented interface, and add additional steps to integrate and test at those interfaces. It is much faster to have a single team that is able to view, edit, build, and test the entire system without needing to communicate via documents when they need to share information.